# is it posible to add anime.js in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, anime.js

Does someone know how to add Anime.js script in Wordpress?
Is it possible?
If yes, is there a plug-in?

```
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('animejs', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/anime.js", array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('animejs');
    wp_register_script('scriptjs', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/script.js", array('animejs'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('scriptjs');
}
add_action('init', 'load_my_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible! You could `enqueue` it using `wp_enqueue_script` function, like so:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_them_function_to_load_files');

function your_them_function_to_load_files()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('handle_for_animejs', get_theme_file_uri('/js/anime.js'), '', "1.5", TRUE);
}
```

The code goes into the `functions.php` of your active theme.

> [WordPress `wp_enqueue_script` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)